# Extracting a class in Python using BeautifulSoup: class name in view source doesn't match the code that is working

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup, find

I am testing the usage of BeautifulSoup in Python. The page that I am looking at is [**this**](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AACG?p=AACG&.tsrc=fin-srch). 
Let's say I want to capture the current price of the stock. If I look at the page source I will see this name for the class of `span` that has the price:

```
"Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"
```

Here is part of the page source (I used chrome browser) that has that class:

[image]

But if I use it in the Python code as:

```
for span in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'}):
    price = span.text.strip()
```

It doesn't give me the price (the price ion this example is 0.8000). I found a code that actually gives me the price but the class name on the code is a little different. This code works:

```
for span in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)'}):
    price = span.text.strip()
```

Why the class name that is actually working is different than what I see on the page source? How the correct class name that works can be found?

Comment: _Here is part of the page source (I used chrome browser) that has that class_ What is rendered in Chrome can be drastically different from what you get using requests (or urllib, etc.), don't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how can I find the correct class name?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote in my comment...?

Comment: Yes, I did but it is still unclear to me how can I find the class name. Maybe you are an expert and it is clear for you. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamic. You do get all that info from the json response though. not sure what you want, but something like:

```
import requests


data = requests.get('https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AACG?region=US&lang=en-US&includePrePost=false&interval=2m&range=1d&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance').json()


    data = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']

    previous = data['previousClose']
    current = data['regularMarketPrice']

    change = round(current-previous, 4)

    chng_prct = (change/previous) *100

    if change > 0:
        sign = '+'
    else:
        sign = ''

    print ('%.04f  %s%.04f (%s%.02f%%)' %(current, sign, round(change,4), sign, chng_prct))
```

**Output:**

```
0.8000  +0.0283 (+3.67%)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to find the correct class names?

Comment: The class names would be dynamic. I suppose it is possible with Selenium. But honestly, all the data on the graph is working that json response.

Comment: For example at the bottom of the page it says `Fair Value` and it shows `overvalued` how can I get that using the json response you are suggesting?

Comment: @TJ1 I’ll take a look tomorrow and let you know. Are you familiar with json?